# python 3.6.3 (OOPS)

Tags: python, oop

```
import math
class Circle():
    def __init__(self,radius,centre):
        self.radius=radius
        self.centre=centre

    def circumference():
        return 2.0*math.pi*self.radius 


c1 = Circle(1.0, (0.5 , 1.0))
c2 = Circle(1.5, (-0.5 , 2.0))

print(c1.radius)
print(c2.radius)
print(c1.circumference)
print(c2.circumference)
```

Output:

```
1.0
1.5
<bound method Circle.circumference of <__main__.Circle object at 0x7facb18214a8>>
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: What error?....

Comment: There is no Error here. You are printing the function signature. Try calling it instead `c1.circumference()`.

Comment: Also you need to pass `self` on the `circumference` definition.

Comment: Thanks ... I figured it out. i need to pass "self" on the circumference.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you have forgot to give braces after `circumference`. As `circumference` is a method of `Class Circle` you need to call this as `circumference()`. Also you need to pass `self` inside the method/function `circumference` to access `radius` (which is defined in `__init__`) inside `circumference`

```
import math
class Circle():
    def __init__(self,radius,centre):
        self.radius=radius
        self.centre=centre

    def circumference(self):
        return 2.0*math.pi*self.radius 


c1 = Circle(1.0, (0.5 , 1.0))
c2 = Circle(1.5, (-0.5 , 2.0))

print(c1.radius)
print(c2.radius)
print(c1.circumference())
print(c2.circumference())
```

Comment: This might be true, but this isn't what the question is asking.

Comment: Sorry for wrong indentation. I have modified the code you can check this now.